# Ionic Build Error: occurred configuring root project 'Android'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building ionic cordova project currently. But prints out with the following error.[image]

The following is my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=../gradle-2.13-all.zip
```

The following build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-2.13-all'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.13'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your current dependencies classpath from

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-2.13-all'
    }
```

to

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
```

Let me know if this doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: It still have error. But I solved my problem by copy and the file from android platform and paste it to android studio folder. Next, i  build my android apk in android studio.

Comment: okay.. running in android studio once will fix the issue i guess.

Comment: Yes, i guess it cannot find the android sdk path. Anyway, I had solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For others who are coming late here, just open your android project under $(Project_Root)\platforms\android in android studio. Then android studio will take care of downloading all the right dependencies.